# Jquery off('click') on('click') bind and unbind

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some buttons (Datatable button to export data) I need to prevent direct data download for that I am implementing OTP so when user first click on button its hows user a dialog box where he/she need to put OTP then if OTP matches then I need to remove .off("click"); method so that buttons can work again. on document ready I add this event like below

```
$(".dt-buttons button").each(function(){
    $(this).off("click");
});
```

Now how can i remove this **.off("click");** so buttons can work again like default

Comment: Show us the rest of code, I guess you need to attach the event again using `.on()`

Comment: you better go with a flag variable canDownload and do a if in the click event then unbinding events

Comment: Somehow If one dont want to add class and then there must be a way to remove this .off("click") handler. Will .on('click', function(){
     $(this).trigger('click');
    }); can work???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the use of common class with event delegation `on()` instead of detaching/attaching the event every time, you could give your button a common class example `click_event` and remove/add class as you want like :

```
$(".dt-buttons button").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("click_event");
});

//When you want to attach the event 
$('your_selector').addClass("click_event");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will attach the normal behavior again on your element

```
             $("Your_selectors").on('click', function(){
                    $(this).trigger('click');
                });
```